# javascript regex if statement for 2 different input values

Tags: javascript, regex

i have the following validation on a form field:

```
$(".controlscard input").blur(function() {
var re = /^(?:[0-9]+[a-z]|[a-z]+[0-9])[a-z0-9]*$/i;
if(re.test(document.getElementById("register_coachcard_no").value))
{
   $(this).css('border-color','green');
     $(this).siblings('.info').css('display','none');
     $(this).siblings('.error').css('display','none');
     $(this).siblings('.valid').css('display','inline-block');   
    $("#email_error40111").hide();

}
else
{
      $(this).css('border-color','red');
     $(this).siblings('.info').css('display','none');
     $(this).siblings('.valid').css('display','none');
     $(this).siblings('.error').css('display','inline-block');
   $('#registerErrors').show();
  $('#email_error40111').remove();
  $('#registerErrors').append('<p id="email_error40111">Coachcard must contain at least 1 letter and 1 number</p>');
}});
```

The above basically checks if the entered content contains 1 letter and 1 number.

I need to put something in place where, if the value length is 8 characters, it will need to check for upto 2 letters, and then 6 numbers.

If the value length is 9 characters, then only numbers can be entered.

Any suggestions on what i can do?

Cheers, Dan

Comment: `/^[a-zA-Z]\d|[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{6}|\d{9}$/i` - Is this what you want?

Comment: what does that cover?

Comment: Exactly as you said. `|` specifies a logical OR. (1 letter, one number OR two letters, 6 numbers OR 9 numbers).

Comment: yes, just tested! i need to be able to allow 1 or 2 letters with the length of 8, not just 1

Comment: Sorry just tested again! all ok :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a regex like this:

```
/^[a-zA-Z]\d|[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{6}|\d{9}$/i
```

The `|` indicates a logical OR, so if one of these holds, it will match:

- 1 letter followed by 1 number
- 2 letters followed by 6 numbers
- 9 numbers

You mentioned that you wanted to match 1 or 2 letters in the second case, but I wasn't sure how this fit with your requirement of 8 characters. You could modify it to accept 1 or 2 letters for 7 or 8 total characters like so:

```
/^[a-zA-Z]\d|[a-zA-Z]{1,2}\d{6}|\d{9}$/i
```

**Edit:**

From comments, adjusted regex:

```
/^[a-zA-Z]\d|[a-zA-Z]{1}\d{7}|[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{6}|\d{9}$/i
```

Comment: just looking at this again, the 8 character value will be to contain a maximum of 2 letters and maximum of 7 numbers randomly. your above answer i believe only allows letters at the beginning. Is that right?